# how to transform image from one coordinate frame to another coordinate frame using c++

Tags: c++, opencv, ros

I have two images from two different cameras, for which I have done both intrinsic and extrinsic calibration.

I have done transforming point clouds(3D) from both the cameras to base_link frame and added together(point cloud registration).

I wanted to do the same for 2D images. That is, I want to transform both the images and add it together so that I get one large image as if taken from one single camera.

Is my approach correct. If so How would I do it.

Thanks in advance.

**Update**

This is what im trying to do,

```
    listener->waitForTransform(reference_frame, camera_link, ros::Time(0), ros::Duration(5.0));
    listener->lookupTransform(reference_frame, camera_link,  ros::Time(0), transform);

    cv::Mat t(4,4,CV_64F, cvScalar(0.0));

    t.at<double>(3,0) = transform.getOrigin().getX();
    t.at<double>(3,1) = transform.getOrigin().getY();
    t.at<double>(3,2) = transform.getOrigin().getZ();

    t.at<double>(0,0) = transform.getRotation().getX() / transform.getRotation().getW();
    t.at<double>(1,1) = transform.getOrigin().getY() / transform.getRotation().getW();
    t.at<double>(2,2) = transform.getOrigin().getZ() / transform.getRotation().getW();

    t.at<double>(3,0) = 1;
    t.at<double>(3,1) = 1;
    t.at<double>(3,2) = 1;

    t.at<double>(3,3) = 1;

    cv::Mat inputImag = cv_ptr->image;
    cv::Mat dest;
    cv::Size size(inputImag.cols,inputImag.rows);
    cv::warpAffine(inputImag, dest, t, size);
```

Im getting the following error,

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed ((M0.type() == CV_32F || M0.type() == CV_64F) && M0.rows == 2 && M0.cols == 3) in warpAffine, file /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.8+dfsg1/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp, line 3455
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.8+dfsg1/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp:3455: error: (-215) (M0.type() == CV_32F || M0.type() == CV_64F) && M0.rows == 2 && M0.cols == 3 in function warpAffine
```

Can someone help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Unclear to me. If stitching is what you want, there's a lot of litterature on that already, start from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_stitching).

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe I saw opencv documentation and got warpAffine(), transform(), perspectiveTransform(), warpPerspective(). But not sure which gives me the result i want.

Comment: @kebs not exactly image stitching using features extraction etc, but I already have transformation relationship between two cameras, so I just wanted to transform one of the image and add to other.

Comment: Seems like `warpAffine()` doesn't like floating-point matrices... You considered upgrading Opencv to 3.X ? Not sure this has been corrected, but I'd give it a try.